# How do I edit .editorconfig on Github

Tags: github

I created a file called ".editorconfig" with indent_size = 4, but github rejects it when I try to upload it saying "this file is hidden"

Comment: Can you show the flow of commands you used to upload it to github? This is very much a valid filename, and many repositories use it.

Comment: Just figured it out.  In the upload files window, it says drag or choose files.  Dragging doesn't work for .editorconfig, but choosing works fine.